# Update a value in a dataframe depending on matching data in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have a tricky problem which I will do my best to explain.

I have two dataframes, the important columns being `uID` (unique identifier) and `b`(a value indicating the genotype).
In one dataframe, `delsFB`, each `uID` appears only once (note:`uIDs` are not necessarily consecutive). In the other, `delsOB`, different `uID`s can appear variable numbers of times (ranging from 1 to about 100 occurences) on different rows.
I need to match the `uIDs` in `delsFB` to those in `delsOB` and update the `b` column with a new value.

The workflow:

1. For each row of `delsOB`, look for rows in `delsFB` with the same `uID`.
2. If any of the matching rows in `delsOB` have the b value `KP` and another contains `CP`, enter the value `NP` into `delsFB$b`.
3. Otherwise, if any rows contain `KP` but none contain `CP`, enter the value `KP` into `delsFB$b`.
4. If any rows contain `CP` but none contain `KP`, enter the value `CP` into `delsFB$b`.
5. Any other situations should return `NP` as well.

I hope that made sense, and thanks very much for any assistance. Here are two small example dataframes made with dput:

dels$FB:

```
structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), pos_c = c(28522L, 29000L, 29211L, 29423L, 
29462L, 29552L, 29766L, 29791L, 29885L, 29946L, 29986L, 30157L, 
30587L, 30871L), uID = c(24L, 33L, 44L, 56L, 62L, 68L, 76L, 80L, 
86L, 91L, 92L, 101L, 141L, 161L), pos_k = c(28523L, 29011L, 29221L, 
29427L, 29462L, 29551L, 29766L, 29790L, 29887L, 29946L, 29953L, 
30123L, 30557L, 30841L), seq_c = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", 
"G"), class = "factor"), seq_sk = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "C", 
"G"), class = "factor"), type_c = c(complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
complex(real=0, imaginary=NA)), type_k = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "d", class = "factor"), 
    Var_len = c(2L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 34L, 2L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L), reads_all = c(20L, 25L, 27L, 18L, 17L, 12L, 
    26L, 26L, 29L, 27L, 16L, 26L, 47L, 42L), deletions = c(0L, 
    0L, 5L, 1L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), insertions = c(0L, 
    1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 24L, 25L, 1L, 1L, 47L, 0L), C = c(0L, 
    0L, 20L, 1L, 0L, 11L, 25L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 11L, 22L, 0L, 1L), 
    T = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 
    0L), G = c(20L, 24L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 26L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 40L), k = c(0L, 0L, 5L, 1L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L), c = c(20L, 24L, 20L, 16L, 0L, 11L, 25L, 
    26L, 24L, 25L, 11L, 22L, 47L, 40L), SNPreads = c(20L, 24L, 
    25L, 17L, 15L, 11L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 26L, 13L, 23L, 47L, 41L
    ), b = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CP", "KP", "NP"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("chrom", 
"pos_c", "uID", "pos_k", "seq_c", "seq_sk", "type_c", "type_k", 
"Var_len", "reads_all", "deletions", "insertions", "A", "C", 
"T", "G", "k", "c", "SNPreads", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

delsOB:

```
structure(list(chrom = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), pos_c = c(28523L, 29001L, 29002L, 29212L, 29213L, 
29214L, 29215L, 29216L, 29217L, 29424L, 29425L, 29426L, 29427L, 
29428L, 29463L, 29464L, 29553L, 29767L, 29792L, 29886L, 29887L, 
29947L, 29948L, 29949L, 29950L, 29951L, 29952L, 29953L, 29954L, 
29955L, 29956L, 29957L, 29958L, 29959L, 29960L, 29961L, 29962L, 
29963L, 29964L, 29965L, 29966L, 29967L, 29968L, 29969L, 29970L, 
29971L, 29972L, 29973L, 29974L, 29975L, 29976L, 29977L, 29978L, 
29979L, 29987L, 30158L, 30588L, 30589L, 30590L, 30872L), uID = c(24L, 
33L, 33L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 
62L, 62L, 68L, 76L, 80L, 86L, 86L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 
91L, 92L, 101L, 141L, 141L, 141L, 161L), pos_k = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "-", class = "factor"), 
    seq_c = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "C", "G", "T"), class = "factor"), 
    seq_sk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "-", class = "factor"), 
    type_c = c(complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), 
    complex(real=0, imaginary=NA), complex(real=0, imaginary=NA)
    ), type_k = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "d", class = "factor"), 
    Var_len = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
    34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L), reads_all = c(20L, 
    24L, 21L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
    16L, 17L, 17L, 12L, 26L, 26L, 29L, 29L, 27L, 27L, 19L, 20L, 
    17L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 26L, 47L, 45L, 45L, 42L), deletions = c(18L, 
    0L, 1L, 25L, 24L, 24L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
    12L, 0L, 0L, 11L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 22L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 
    20L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 38L), insertions = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), A = c(2L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 3L), 
    C = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 4L, 1L, 16L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 8L, 
    2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L), T = c(0L, 24L, 19L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 
    2L, 5L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L), G = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    2L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), k = c(18L, 0L, 1L, 25L, 
    24L, 24L, 21L, 20L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 0L, 0L, 
    11L, 21L, 25L, 23L, 22L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 20L, 44L, 44L, 
    44L, 38L), c = c(2L, 24L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 2L, 
    9L, 1L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    3L, 4L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L), SNPreads = c(20L, 24L, 1L, 25L, 
    26L, 24L, 22L, 26L, 25L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 14L, 15L, 0L, 0L, 
    11L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 23L, 25L, 11L, 18L, 10L, 17L, 12L, 
    10L, 9L, 12L, 10L, 12L, 11L, 12L, 11L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 10L, 
    9L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 13L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 
    12L, 9L, 13L, 24L, 46L, 44L, 44L, 41L), b = structure(c(3L, 
    1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("CP", 
    "HP", "KP", "NP"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("chrom", 
"pos_c", "uID", "pos_k", "seq_c", "seq_sk", "type_c", "type_k", 
"Var_len", "reads_all", "deletions", "insertions", "A", "C", 
"T", "G", "k", "c", "SNPreads", "b"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

EDIT: Sorry, forgot expected output - for these example datasets, the `b` column in `delsFB` should be updated to:
24 KP, 33 CP, 44 KP, 56 KP, 62 NP, 68 KP, 76 KP, 80 KP, 86 KP, 91 KP, 92 KP, 101 KP, 141 KP, 161 KP.

Note that currently, e.g. `uID` `91` has 34 instances in `delsOB`, but it still only needs one `KP` to be considered type `KP`. Ideally the rule would depend somewhat on length e.g. if there are 34 instances, at least 50% of them have to be `KP` for `b=KP`, but if there are only ~5 instances, it must be 80% of them. However this may make the problem too complicated.

Comment: can you explain step 2 in your workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this may be to loop through the unique values in delsOB, check your desired conditions, and then update delsFB. The following code should do this, and can be modified to include additional conditions (such as changing the result based on the number of instances).

```
# Save delsFB to a new data frame so results can be compared afterward. 
delsFB_new <- delsFB

# Loop through the unique uID values in delsOB.
for (unique_id in unique(delsOB$uID)) {
  # Subset delsOB for the current unique uID.
  currrent_delsOB_subset <- delsOB[delsOB$uID == unique_id, ]
  # Assign desired value to result based on the conditions.
  if ("KP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b & "CP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    result <- "NP"
  }
  else if ("KP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    result <- "KP"
  }
  else if ("CP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    result <- "CP"
  }
  else {
    result <- "NP"
  }
  # Insert the result into delsFB$b.
  delsFB_new[delsFB_new$uID == unique_id, ]$b <- result
}
```

EDIT: Here is a second version that uses conditional logic for the additional check for "KP" proportion based on the number of instances.

```
# Save delsFB to a new data frame so results can be compared afterward. 
delsFB_new <- delsFB

# Loop through the unique uID values in delsOB.
for (unique_id in unique(delsOB$uID)) {
  # Subset delsOB for the current unique uID.
  currrent_delsOB_subset <- delsOB[delsOB$uID == unique_id, ]
  # Assign desired value to result based on the conditions.
  if ("KP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b & "CP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    result <- "NP"
  }
  else if ("KP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    # Nested conditional logic to ensure a minimum proportion of "KP" values, according to the number of instances.
    if (length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b) <= 7 & length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b[currrent_delsOB_subset$b == "KP"]) >= .8*length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b)) {
      result <- "KP"
    }
    else if (length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b) > 7 & length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b[currrent_delsOB_subset$b == "KP"]) >= .5*length(currrent_delsOB_subset$b)) {
      result <- "KP"
    }
  }
  else if ("CP" %in% currrent_delsOB_subset$b) {
    result <- "CP"
  }
  else {
    result <- "NP"
  }
  # Insert the result into delsFB$b.
  delsFB_new[delsFB_new$uID == unique_id, ]$b <- result
}
```

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to modify it to fulfill an extra criteria? Ideally the rule would depend somewhat on length e.g. if there are 34 instances, at least 50% of them have to be KP for b=KP, but if there are only ~5 instances, it must be 80% of them. This isn't essential though. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Glad it worked! It sounds like you want to add an additional check to make sure that some minimum "KP" proportion threshold is met, based on the current number of instances. Once you figure out your logic precisely, you can do this with nested conditional logic. I've added a second version of the code to get you started. Just look for the comment that starts with "# Nested conditional logic..." and modify the code that follows based on your desired logic.

Comment: Thanks again, that's extremely helpful :)